# Exception when using Invoke

Tags: vb.net, invoke

My programming skills are very basic. I am trying to make a client/server communication program using UDP in Visual Basic Express 2008.
It is a simple receiver for messages another app I've wrote sends.

The problem is that it works fine when it receives from 1 computer. If I have 2 or more computers sending, it throws exceptions quite regularly in the Invoke line.

Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub MigraReceiver_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        StartListening()

    End sub

    Private Sub ProcessPacket(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
            Dim Data As Byte()

            SyncLock UDPReadLock
                Try
                    Data = ListenSocket.EndReceive(ar, New System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 0))
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' Handle any exceptions here
                Finally
                    Try
                        UDPSyncResult = ListenSocket.BeginReceive(AddressOf ProcessPacket, UDPState)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        ' Do nothing
                    End Try
                End Try
            End SyncLock

            ' Only attempt to process if we received data
            If Data.Length > 0 Then
                Dim Thread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf SetText)
                Thread.Start(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Data))
                'SetText(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Data))
            End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartListening()
            Try
                ListenSocket = New System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient
                ListenSocket.Client.SetSocketOption(Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel.Socket, Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)
                ListenSocket.Client.Bind(New System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, listenPort))
                UDPSyncResult = ListenSocket.BeginReceive(AddressOf ProcessPacket, UDPState)
            Catch ex As Exception
                'Handle an exception
            End Try
    End Sub


    Private Delegate Sub SetTextDelegate(ByVal [text] As String)


    Private Sub SetText(ByVal text As String)




            Dim espera_ordem As Integer = 0


            If Me.TabControl1.InvokeRequired Then

                'THIS IS WHERE IT THROWS THE EXCEPTION:
                Me.TabControl1.Invoke(New SetTextDelegate(AddressOf SetText), New Object() {text})   


            Else


            'Does GUI updates.

        End if

    End Sub
```

It throws an exception 'Array out of bounds' in the
Me.TabControl1.Invoke(New SetTextDelegate(AddressOf SetText), New Object() {text}) 
line.

I've been trying, testing and searching for 3 days without success :( 
It seems the problem occurs when I receive several packets in a short time.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Regards,
Mike

P.S. - Here is the complete SetText:

```
Private Sub SetText(ByVal text As String)

    Dim espera_ordem As Integer = 0

    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New SetTextDelegate(AddressOf SetText), New Object() {text})
    Else

        Dim partes() As String
        Dim subpartes() As String
        Dim login, maquina, mensagem As String

        partes = text.Split("-")
        subpartes = partes(0).Split(" ")
        maquina = Trim(subpartes(3))
        login = Trim(subpartes(4))
        mensagem = Trim(partes(1))

        Dim myIndex As Integer = logins.IndexOf(login)
        If myIndex = -1 Then
            TabControl1.Visible = True
            Dim NewTab As New TabPage
            NewTab.Name = login + "_tab"
            Dim text1 As New TextBox
            text1.Name = login + "_txt"
            text1.Multiline = True
            text1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
            text1.Size = New Size(570, 220)
            Me.TabControl1.Controls.Add(NewTab)
            NewTab.Controls.Add(text1)
            Dim but1 As New Button
            but1.Name = login + "_btn"
            but1.Location = New Point(3, 234)
            but1.Text = "Ai"
            but1.Visible = False
            AddHandler but1.Click, AddressOf Me.but1_Click
            NewTab.Controls.Add(but1)
            NewTab.Text = maquina + " " + login
            logins.Add(login)
            text1.Text = Now.ToString("t") + " - " + mensagem
            NewTab.Select()
        Else
            Dim tb1 As TextBox = CType(TabControl1.TabPages.Item(TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1).Controls.Find(login + "_txt", True)(0), TextBox)
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + Environment.NewLine + Now.ToString("t") + " - " + mensagem
        End If
    End if  
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the contents of `text`??  Maybe it's blank/empty/Nothing.  Test it before invoking the delegate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. text is not empty. I've tested that. In the catch I've print the variable and it is never empty.  :(

Comment: Try changing `Me.TabControl1.Invoke(...)` to just `Me.Invoke(...)` - i.e. don't reference the tab control, reference the form.

Comment: "Array out of bounds" is not an exception message that .NET ever generates.  It might be talking about an *index* that's out of bounds.  Posting **accurate** information is very important to get help.  This is includes having to post the stack trace of the exception so it is clear exactly where this goes wrong.  Use Debug + Exception, tick the Thrown checkbox to get the most accurate stack trace before Invoke() mangles it.

Comment: @Grim: Using just Me.Invoke also results in exceptions. :(   If I receive messages from 1 computer it runs great. If I run the sending app in 2 computers at the same time....I get these exceptions.

Comment: @HansPassant: You are right. I typed the error from memory but you should understand what I meant. The correct exception is "Index was outside the bounds of the array." on exactly that Me.Invoke ...  line.

Comment: We need to see the code where it says `' Do GUI updates`.

Comment: @Grim:  I've added the the entire SetText to the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is going to be too long for a comment, so I've had to make it an answer.  For anyone else reading, this follows on from the comments on the OP.

I know you said that you're checking `text` isn't null, or empty, but are you checking it's got a dash and a space in??  The following code;

```
    partes = text.Split("-")
    subpartes = partes(0).Split(" ")
    maquina = Trim(subpartes(3))
    login = Trim(subpartes(4))
    mensagem = Trim(partes(1))
```

ASSUMES you have a dash and spaces to split the data on.  If not, you're going to get the `Index was outside the bounds of the array` exception.

To test, try this;

```
Try
    partes = text.Split("-")
    subpartes = partes(0).Split(" ")
    maquina = Trim(subpartes(3))
    login = Trim(subpartes(4))
    mensagem = Trim(partes(1))

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SPLITTING FAILED!!")
End Try
```

That should help you along the way!

Comment: Grim: I assume because I have. ALWAYS :)  I've tried that but no exception there. Also... it would not work when only 1 computer is sending but it does. I am loosing my mind here  :(

Comment: Hmmm.  OK, put a `Try... Catch` around your entire routine, produce the error and then examine the FULL stack trace - one line at a time!  It's hard to see what's going on with your network; but there's ports, collisions, and all that jazz to be checked if it's only happening with > 1 client.

Comment: Ok....

I think I've narrowed the error to these 2 lines using try/catch:       Dim tb1 As TextBox = CType(TabControl1.TabPages.Item(TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1).Controls.Find(login + "_txt", True)(0), TextBox)
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + Environment.NewLine + Now.ToString("t") + " - " + mensagem                   

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's a whole new problem.  I suggest you start a new question for it - this one's getting a little stale and OT!  Make sure you give the exception details!